# CMake ExternalProject_Add, libraries are downloaded to the project directory not in the default one C:/ProgramFiles

Tags: c++, cmake, eigen

**What I am doing:**
I have a working example that downloads Eigen library using `ExternalProject_Add` command.
After I run the CMakeLists.txt I see that the library installed in the project directory.

**Question:**
What would be a way to install the library in the default directory `C:/ProgramFiles` ?
Because it means that each time, I create a project I will download same libraries multiple times, meaning there will be multiple copies of them in my computer which I would like to avoid.

**Code:**

[image]

```
################################################################################
#Project name and defaults
#cmake  -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64  ..  && cmake  --build . --config Release 
################################################################################
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(my_project)

if (MSVC)
 message("Petras is talking to you: MSVC Compiler, this line is not needed if MinGW compiler is used")
 #Without this message no .dll file is created, place ir after the project name
 set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

 #This one copies .dlls to project build directory
 set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
 message(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)

endif (MSVC)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE OFF)

################################################################################
#ExternalProject
################################################################################
include(ExternalProject)

################################################################################
#EIGEN
################################################################################

set(EIGEN_BUILD_DIR   ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/eigen)
set(EIGEN_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/eigen3)
set(EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR ${EIGEN_INSTALL_DIR})

ExternalProject_Add(
    eigen
    URL https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/archive/3.3.7/eigen-3.3.7.tar.gz
    PREFIX ${EIGEN_BUILD_DIR}
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND
      ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${EIGEN_BUILD_DIR}/src/eigen/Eigen ${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR}/Eigen 
      && ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${EIGEN_BUILD_DIR}/src/eigen/unsupported ${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR}/unsupported
    TEST_COMMAND ""
)
include_directories(SYSTEM ${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR})

################################################################################
#Link to the project
################################################################################
add_executable(my_exe "main.cpp")
add_dependencies(my_exe eigen)
```

Comment: This is contrary to the design of ExternalProject. If you want shared, pre-compiled binaries, you should use `find_package` and either build your dependencies manually or use `vcpkg`, which gives you the best of both worlds (project isolation and binary caching).

Comment: I think it would be deeply irresponsible to do exactly what you're asking (installing libraries to the system path as part of the build). I would personally consider this a malicious behavior.

Comment: what about "super build" concept, is it also done like this in the current directory instead of default one?

Comment: A super build is just a build with a bunch of ExternalProject calls that wire together some sub-builds. Everything occurs locally within a build-output directory.